# Automatic download .cvs file from specific website.

Tags: php

I want to download "Bhavcopy.cvs" file form "nseindia.com" on everyday at 5 pm.

So, I want php code that automatic download this file from "nse" website...

Please help

I tried following code.

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm/cm07APR2014bhav.csv.zip');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm/cm07APR2014bhav.csv
```

Comment: That's not going to work, if you want to automatically, download every day, you need a scheduler like a cron job.If you setup a cron job, then you need a script to save the file, so something like this will work <?php $data =file_get_contents("http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm/cm07APR2014bhav.csv"); file_put_contents("localfile.csv, $data); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use php's native CURL function to fetch pages from various resources

Documentation: https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Use a Cronjob to schedule the php script daily.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way you use [**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), you can load a file into a variable. if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. You can parse the result with [**str_getcsv**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$data = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm/cm07APR2014bhav.csv'));
```

If you need to set **specific headers** you use an other **delimeters manualy**.

If you getting **access denied** add following **header parameter**.

---

#### readfile() function

```
    $fname = "nsecsv";
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fname");
    readfile('http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm/cm07APR2014bhav.csv');
```

---

#### cURL function

```
$url = 'http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/homepage_eq.htm/cm07APR2014bhav.csv';
curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Check this great [**cURL**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) documetation

Comment: The page gives access denied so you'll need CURL to pass authentication headers.

Comment: If you getting **access denied** add answer **header parameter**.

Comment: Thx for this help but the problem is cm07APR2014bhav.csv file name changes everyday as new date bhavcopy posted..